# Two Datasets one query

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report using two datasets.

The first has a user id which i need to link to the second one to pull the information required. The second dataset query needs the user.id before the query will work   Is there anyway i am able to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain your scenario little clear. Are you trying to have a cascaded parameters in SSRS reports? Say, You need to select a Product from the dropdown (Bat, Ball, Nets etc) and depending on the selection another dropdown will be loaded with the relevant data say (For Ball - Basket ball, Volley ball, Foot ball etc)

Comment: Basically what i need is for the report linked to dataset1 to run initially. Dataset 2 needs the userid before it can find the information required as i need to do 'Where ref is 'CD' + userid'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a subreport and from there pass the user id that is returned from the first dataset into the subreports parameter.

If you have not used subreports, here are some articles: (Assuming you are using Crystal Reports)

http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=1137